# Tweenjs and $.ajax giveme an error in animations

Tags: jquery, ajax, animation, createjs

I 'm using CreateJS to achieve animations but the problem happens when I make an AJAX call while the animation is running, after completing the ajax call, the animation is running ends but the new animations do not work and it's like the CreateJS object had disabled , any ideas or someone who has been the same to me? The code is rather long but basically contains:

```
 function Core(){
  _private.stage.update();
  _helper.hideLoading();
  createjs.Ticker.setFPS(100);
  createjs.Ticker.on("tick",onTickEvent);
 }

 function onTickEvent(event) {
  _private.stage.update(event);

createjs.Tween.get(_private.obj)
.wait(_waitTime)
.to({ alpha: 0, x: _global.objInitX, y: _global.objInitY },50,createjs.Ease.getPowInOut(1))
.to({ alpha: 1, x: _global.objFinX, y: _global.objFinY },5500, createjs.Ease.getPowInOut(2))
.call( onCompleteEvent );
```

}

My first call if it works and this on page load but then I'll use a SetInterval Javascript to use the $ .ajax

```
SetInterval(function(){
 $.ajax({

 });
},30000);
```

Im getting crazy for this, sorry for my bad english.
Grettings.

Comment: `setInterval` starts with a lowercase "s". What errors are you getting in the console?

Comment: Sorry , I know I put in the title that gave me an error , but does not show me any error message, just makes no animation.

Comment: Can you post your full code for the `$.ajax({});` and the context in which it is being called? I have a suspicion that you have a scope problem.

Comment: Thank God this was resolved , I ll put this answer bellow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks God this was resolved, I used it:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('POST', _sys.Host + path, true);
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
xhr.onreadystatechange = function()
{
  if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200)
  {
     onsucc(xhr.responseText); 
  }
};
xhr.send(data);
```

I dont know why canvas or Tweenjs malfunctions when calling $ .ajax.
 
All is ok now. 
 
Thanks for help. 
 
Regards.